# googledrive or onedrive as localdrive in linux server

Tags: linux, google-drive-api, onedrive, webmin, grive

I want to access to googledrive or onedrive as local drive or local folder in linux server. I tried to search internet and found grive and syncdrive for linux.are these tools can be used in linux servers? or Do exist simple script for control panels like webmin , Kloxo that mount googledrive?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to googledrive:it's aws bucket!
this tutorial:
[S3 Bucket Mounting as a File System in Linux using S3fs and S3fuse](http://walkintocloud.com/2014/01/s3-bucket-mounting-as-a-file-system-in-linux-using-s3fs-and-s3fuse/)

this is good,easy management,low price an fast especially for geoserver tiles([geoserver](http://geoserver.org))